# Can you explain me why outpot is so?

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    lst = []
    nums = []
        
    for i in range(N):
        a = input()
        temp = a.split()
        if 'insert' in temp:
            lst.insert(int(temp[1]), int(temp[2]))
        elif 'print' in temp:
            nums.append(lst)
        elif 'remove' in temp:
            del lst[lst.index(int(temp[1]))]
        elif 'append' in temp:
            lst.append(int(temp[1]))
        elif 'sort' in temp:
            lst.sort()
        elif 'pop' in temp:
            lst.pop(-1)
        elif 'reverse' in temp:
            lst = lst.reverse()
    for i in nums:
        print(i)
```

Input

```
    12

    insert 0 5

    insert 1 10

    insert 0 6

    print

    remove 6

    append 9

    append 1

    sort

    print

    pop

    reverse

    print
```

Output

```
    [9, 5, 1]

    [9, 5, 1]

    None
```

Expected output

```
    [6, 5, 10]

    [1, 5, 9, 10]

    [9, 5, 1]
```

I am doing task on HackerRank and I almost have done it, but suddenly in every loop in 'for i in range(N)' program add the last list three times independent on Input.

I have tried a lot of debug tests, but I can't find mistake in my script.

Comment: Add `print(lst)` and `print(nums)` at the end of your first for-loop and you see what is going on. As you are editing `lst`, `nums` changes with it

Comment: You can also upvote the solution given by @TCMolenaar since it solves your problem completely

Comment: Adding to @TCMolenaar answer, have a look at [Mutable vs immutable](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJz9SEkI37AhX7S2wGHalCDEMQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fmutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python%2F&usg=AOvVaw33mMFDCCjYNPkqJkWHQA33)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two things that need to change:

1. `lst.reverse()` instead of `lst = lst.reverse()`
2. As you are appending, removing etc. to `lst`, the list that you saved in `nums` will change with it. You need to use `nums.append(lst.copy())` instead of `nums.append(lst)`

The full code becomes:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    lst = []
    nums = []

    for i in range(N):
        a = input()
        temp = a.split()
        if 'insert' in temp:
            lst.insert(int(temp[1]), int(temp[2]))
        elif 'print' in temp:
            nums.append(lst.copy())
        elif 'remove' in temp:
            del lst[lst.index(int(temp[1]))]
        elif 'append' in temp:
            lst.append(int(temp[1]))
        elif 'sort' in temp:
            lst.sort()
        elif 'pop' in temp:
            lst.pop(-1)
        elif 'reverse' in temp:
            lst.reverse()

    for i in nums:
        print(i)
```